# How to remove wine completely

Tags: package-management, wine

How can I remove the wine folder and all the applications in that folder?

I've tried via synaptic but it keeps showing up in the application menu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/21683

Answer (score 125):

In my case Wine did not get effectively uninstalled using the command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine wine64 libwine fonts-wine
```

So I did the following (**make sure to copy the exact commands**):

```
cd $HOME
rm -r .wine
rm .config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -r .local/share/applications/wine
rm .local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm .local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

These commands delete files stored in hard disk that may lock uninstallation of wine. Quite possibly you will get some warnings about `rm: remove write-protected regular file` here. These can be enforced collectively by using the `f` option, i.e. `rm -f` and `rm -rf` instead of the above... but *be the heck careful that you've actually typed the right paths*!

After deleting the files run command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
```

Do the following to correct any installation error.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: **NOTE**: there are no spaces in the `rm -rf` lines.  Accidentally adding one could [nuke your home folder without prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790532/all-files-gone-hidden).

Comment: This is terribly dangerous and mostly unnecessary.,

Comment: @user1717828 Adding `cd $HOME` and running all the commands with *relative* paths may avoid another accident.

Comment: pagal pila, the suggestion of @IsmaelMiguel is sound: please consider `cd $HOME`; and then the `rm`s with relative paths.

Comment: `$ apt list --installed | sed -E 's|(.*)/.*|\1|' | grep -i wine` get the list of packages and remove them one by one using `sudo apt remove <PACKAGE-NAME>` and you are done.

Comment: If you receive a message like `Virtual packages like 'wine' can't be removed` you can try `sudo apt-get remove winehq-stable --purge`.  Depends on how wine was installed.

Comment: You can also add an asterisk (*) to the `rm -r .local/share/applications/wine*` command. Because there are `wine-extension*` files as well.

Answer (score 18):

First answer is the easy form to get this, but it's incomplete, the complete code is:

If you've installed wine from the official Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine --purge
```

If you've installed wine from their official PPA:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine-1.3 --purge
```

Next, clean the context menu, menu entries, etc:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.wine
rm -f $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/*wine*
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/*wine*
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/*wine*
```

It needs to reboot the system:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: The command `rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm` is a bad idea, it removes ALL icons which do not have to be wine ones.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Lekensteyn, is needed to delete manualy the icons ins this format "????_" to match with "wine". Sorry for my bad english, i learning it.

Comment: `?` matches a single character. If you want to match wine, just use `rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/wine_*.xpm`. But the latter command already matches any filename with "wine" in it, so it's obsolete.

Comment: You don't need to reboot the system silly, you can simply do sudo apt-get update.

Answer (score 16):

Run these to get rid of menu entries instead of (or in addition to) using "Edit Menus".

```
rm $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -r $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
```

Answer (score 13):

I tried more ways from here and others but didn't work
so i did the following and it worked
if you installed it from [Winehq](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) site you just need to do

1- Press alt+Ctrl+t to open the terminal

2- Type in it `sudo apt-get remove winehq-devel`

Note: if it said that not found try other winehq type to remove what you have install as `sudo apt-get remove winehq-stable` Or `sudo apt-get remove winehq-staging`

3- Type y mean yes to remove it, in the removing in will download some files and a new windows will appear just click tab from your keyboard to click on ok and then yes

4- when it finish do `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

5- it will ask you to do `sudo apt autoremove` you are done now

You can reinstall it or do what you want to do now

If you installed it by Ubuntu software you can remove it by using it too

Comment: Also if you have play on linux or wine tricks you must remove it first

Comment: Only thing that actually works.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me. Most answers assume instaling wine  through a package manager. For those that installed it follwing the instructions on the winehq site , we forgot about it and its easy to assume that we did it through the package manager because that's the usual route for most users (me included) . Thank you man, this has always been bugging me. Finally felt the satisfaction of releasing that unused memory.

Answer (score 8):

### In 11.04 and below (GNOME Classic)

When you install wine, it creates a "wine" menu in your applications menu, and this menu is partly user specific. To remove the menu entries, right click on your menu and click edit menus.

> [image]

Now open the menu editor and disable or remove the wine related entries. You can also remove the `/home/username/.wine` folder be either enabling hidden files in nautilus, or by opening a terminal and typing `rm -rf ~/.wine`.

### 11.04 and up (Unity Desktop).

You need to open the menu editor from the Dash by press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and type `alacarte`. Click on the icon, and the menu editor will come up.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to include the `-f` (force) option in the `rm` command. `rm -r ~/.wine` is much safer than an answer of "yes" on all warnings, because you can't be sure that "yes" will always be the best thing to do.

Comment: in this case it would be safe, he's just removing his wine folder.

Comment: Before proceeding with this sort of command, make sure everything is alright. For any mistake, you can delete all fo your data

Comment: @cruciiedsoul: thanks for the unnecessary warnings on every answer of mine that you can fin. it's rather useless, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Firefeather: The answer below points to http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#uninstall_app which also does rm -rf. Personally I do that everywhere where I know I can safely delete an entire directory and subdirectories. But that is deviating from this question, I guess :-)

Comment: @mydoghasworms: Good point. I guess it's a difference in philosophy; because of Murphy's "law", I avoid force options (`-f`) as much as possible. 8-P

Answer (score 8):

Single command :

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove winehq-stable
```

just change "winehq-stable" according to your condition ( either winehq-devel or winehq-staging) if above doesn't work.

note: this is for them who used winehq

Comment: works on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 4):

If `apt-get --purge autoremove wine` does not do it, maybe your package goes otherwise, like `wine1.6-dev`. Try that that one.

Answer (score 3):

Using some menu editors can cause trouble, as it hides rather than
deletes the menu items - and they stay hidden if you reinstall the apps!

See http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#uninstall_app for tips on how to
uninstall wine and/or all wine apps.

Answer (score 2):

Go to software manager. You will still find wine related packages installed. Remove them. This really works to remove wine from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine` .
After this I had to give `sudo apt-get autoremove`
In my case it solved the problem. Also have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57735/how-to-remove-ttf-mscorefonts-completely) to remove all the ms core fonts.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar problem but after doing

```
apt-get autoremove wine
```

it worked