# Disable wine integration

Tags: wine

I installed winamp 5.6 under wine in ubuntu. Now I have a winamp icon in the desktop, winamp menu entries under the wine menu in the "Application" menu, but worse of all: in nautilus some files (*.mp3 files) are associated with winamp.

This seems to be because ubuntu is trying to "better integrate wine". Here are some specs which all seem to be outdated:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BetterIntegratedWineSpec
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/karmic-wine-integration
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WineIntegration
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BestIntegratedWine

How can I disable this integration?

- File associations should never be set outside of wine.
- Menu entries should never be created outside of wine.
- Icons should never be created outside of wine.
- Basically what goes in wine should stay in wine.

Using ubuntu lucid.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you would need to remove (purge) wine from the ubuntu repositories and download wine from winehq

You could try the ubuntu-wine ppa

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa

See [How do I correctly remove items from Wine Programs menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21681/how-to-correctly-remove-items-from-wine-programs-menu)

For your other items, you would need to file a bug report against wine on launchpad.