# Can't remove shortcut from Ubuntu

Tags: shortcuts

I've tried to install GOG Galaxy to play some games on my girlfriend's PC, however, it didn't work (the installers runs with WINE). But I noticed it created 2 shortcuts, one called "GOG", the other "iTunes" but with GOG Galaxy image.
I was able to remove the "GOG" shortcut using an application called "Main Menu", but can't find that "iTunes" anywhere.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, GNOME 42.5.

I've tried searching those 3 locations, to no avail:

/usr/share/applications

/usr/local/share/applications

~/.local/share/applications

This is the shortcut I can't remove, wrongfully called iTunes using GOG Galaxy image.

[image: This is the shortcut I can't remove, wrongfully called iTunes using GOG Galaxy image.]

Comment: this answers will solve your problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/21681/how-do-i-correctly-remove-items-from-wine-programs-menu