# How to remove ttf-mscorefonts completely?

Tags: wine, fonts

I tried remove the installer itself, but the fonts are still there..Is there away to **COMPLETELY REMOVE** the fonts?

Answer (score 15):

Because of the way the fonts are allowed to be distributed, the package downloads installers and extracts them into their own directory in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`.

To clean up those extracted files, just run this:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts
```

You can be more thorough (run `locate msttcorefonts` to find more places where various helper files are excreted) but the other command should have cleaned up all the fonts.

You might find you need to clear the font cache after this for applications to realise the fonts have gone. Fairly simple:

```
fc-cache -rv
```

Answer (score 9):

You can uninstall the font instead of just remove it.

`sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Then according to @Oli answer, update font cache
`fc-cache -rv`

Comment: +1, all I had to do was the first step (although I used "purge" instead of "remove") and restart my browser to get rid of the uglified fonts that corefonts installed (using Kubuntu 14.04).