# Factory reset for ubuntu 11.10 to really uninstall wine

Tags: 11.10, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove wine completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely)

Is there a way to do a reset for ubuntu 11.10 to really uninstall a software such as wine and all of its remaining components. I installed wine 1.3 using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.3
```

Then I used the software center to uninstall wine but that really didn't uninstalled the whole program because it left some folders in the home directory .wine so is there a way to reset ubuntu or really uninstall wine with terminal commands? can you guys please help with the code for the terminal.

Comment: @belacqua no this is not a duplicate as there was no answer and it was for an unknown wine version. Thankfully burnopereira81 provided kick *UP* support and provided excellent answer.

Comment: I don't think it's different, though @burnopereira81's answer is more direct.  His answer would've worked for the original question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove wine + all configs and files type this in a terminal

`sudo apt-get remove --purge wine1.3`.

After that if there is still a `~/.wine` folder you are free to delete it using

`rm -rf ~/.wine`.

Comment: I get this when I use rm -f ~/.wine rm: cannot remove `/home/user/.wine': Is a directory

Comment: After I uninstalled wine 1.3 thru the softwarecenter I installed wine 1.2 aswell I tried sudo apt-get remove --purge wine1.2 like you suggested for wine1.3 but I get this: dpkg: warning: while removing wine1.2, directory '/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged' not empty so not removed. any help would be awsome.

Comment: try not using the `--purge` flag.

Comment: I got this after using sudo apt-get remove wine1.2: The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 liblcms1:i386
  libqt4-qt3support:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libqt4-test:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.

Comment: I used sudo apt-get autoremove seemed to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Wine stores all its files in .wine/ in your home directory.

Remove the .wine/ directory from your home directory.

Then you use `alacarte` to remove the entries from the menu.