# Uninstall Wine or other programms(Software) from Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

How can I Uninstall Wine or other Programm(Software) from Ubuntu 12.04?
I removed it from Center, but it was not delete from Menu

Comment: Use **Ubuntu Software Center** or **Synaptic** (Install Synaptic using Ubuntu Software Center first). or use the command `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine` See [How to remove wine completely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely).

Comment: Is there other way?

Comment: He possibly has some leaked Wine desktop files from a previous wine install. Probably.