# Wine complete removal from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity

I have installed wine from Ubuntu software centre but I don't need that & want to remove the software completely from my system so please tell me How to completely remove wine from Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely)

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
```

That will uninstall wine but if you want to get rid of wine and anything related to wine run:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine
```

Comment: Note that `sudo apt-get purge wine` doesn't generally remove everything *related* to wine--only wine and its *global* (i.e., systemwide) configuration files. User-specific wine configuration files, Windows apps installed via Wine, and so forth are unaffected by `purge`ing (or any other action carried out via `apt-get`).