# Having broken packages when installing some i386 packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I remember this started when I was trying to install wine. I tried following the instructions on the page, that involved adding the i386 architecture, and installing the `winehq-devel` package, with the `--install-recommends` option.

Except it didn't work at the time, and it gave me some errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 2.0~rc1~ubuntu16.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install it, I get the same error with `wine-devel-i386`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-devel-i386:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.9) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 (>= 10.2~) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.25) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried searching for answers regarding the broken packages and tried a bunch of stuff:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get install -f
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(not by this order, but I found different solutions that mentioned them)

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

doesn't give me any packages either.

I also tried istalling synaptic to check the broken packages, which didn't show me anything.

I also tried installing with aptitude, it gives me options, if I understand how it works, but it either doesn't install the package, or it requires me to remove 1500+ packages, which doesn't seem like a solution to me.

I kinda gave up on it, until I tried to install nvidia drivers. I removed the old version and when I tried to install the `375`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-375 : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I get this again. And if I try to install it individually, with `apt-get install libc6-i386` :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu3) but 2.23-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there anything I could do to try and fix this, or should I just reinstall and get it over with?

Comment: I had already checked that, and it didn't help me.
`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` doesn't show anything, and trying to install with aptitude I already mentioned that it doesn't install and the recommendations are for me to uninstall tons of packages for no reason.

Comment: Did you try any of the other answers on that page? Could you possibly provide the actual order of the commands that you ran that didn't work so we might have some chance of determining where you went wrong? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I tried all of the solutions. Like I said, `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` doesn't give me any packages.

`aptitude` doesn't give me a solution where it installs wine. It's mostly options like these: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/52TfpyXu). 

`apt-get autoremove` again, doesn't remove anything.

If I try to `apt-get update` it runs but it doesn't solve anything. `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` have the same problem, no packages to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that at some point you were attempting to install the development version of wine which some users [had difficulty with.](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=25906)

I believe you may have missed the part in [the instructions](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) that state "If you have previously installed a Wine package from another repository, please remove it and any packages that depend on it (e.g., wine-mono, wine-gecko, winetricks) before attempting to install the WineHQ packages, as they may cause dependency conflicts."

This being the case I recommend that you

1) [remove wine completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely)

2) Remove any other packages that depend on it (e.g., wine-mono, wine-gecko, winetricks) with `sudo apt-get remove wine-mono wine-gecko winetricks`

3) Decide whether to install the [stable Ubuntu repository package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wine&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) version 1.6 at last check (which I use) or the [winehq staging or development package](https://www.winehq.org/download) keeping in mind that **development packages are under development and aren't likely to be very stable.**

3a) To install the stable Ubuntu Repository package issue the command `sudo apt-get install wine`

3b) To install the staging version issue the following commands **in order** 
If and only if your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already): 
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Regardless:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

3c) To install the development version issue the following commands **in order** 
If and only if your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already): 
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Regardless:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

I recommend that you use the stable version from the Ubuntu repositories unless you have a good reason to do otherwise (like you are a developer/tester assisting the wine team)

I so, you should know that users of the staging branch should file bugs [here](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25307), and can now submit test reports to the [AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/)

A great place to go for further assistance with wine or to get involved with the project is https://wiki.winehq.org/Main_Page If you visit it would be a good idea to read the [FAQ.](https://forum.winehq.org/faq.php)

Note: As a rule of thumb, I highly recommend current backups prior to making any changes to your operating system. It makes putting things back to normal far easier. With total power comes total responsibility.

Comment: I had already removed those packages from wine, which I saw from another thread, with the `--purge` option. When I try to install any of the versions, I get a similar error, even tho It comes from different packages: `wine1.6` gives me error on `wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14)`, which gives me [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AqYGD3ze)

The other package, either staging or devel, gives me similar errors: If I try to manually install the packages it says it wont install, i eventually each this: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WBTH5r64).

Comment: Seeing as how you've tried to install all 3 versions again, rather than making a decision and sticking with it, I haven't had enough coffee to wrap my head around this. Hopefully someone else will chime in.