# Uninstall Wine Windows Program Loader completely

Tags: wine, gnome-terminal, winetricks

I'm a new user of ubuntu and have messed up my system because of lack of information.

Few days back i tried to install WINE WINDOWS PROGRAM LOADER v1.8 on my laptop but during the download my pc got shut down and after that any command releated to wine gives me an error.

Now all i want to do is to completely uninstall it and everthing releated to wine.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51553/discussion-on-question-by-user109256-uninstall-wine-windows-program-loader-compl).

Answer (score 1):

The usual `remove` command would leave you their file associations that remain untouched by `remove` operation (for example `.wine` directory).

This situation would leave you wondering what went wrong. If you want a complete uninstall, execute the following commands in Terminal one-by-one:

```
sudo apt remove wine
rm -r "$HOME/.wine"
rm $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -r "$HOME/.local/share/applications/wine"
rm $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

Followed by `purge` command:

```
sudo apt remove --purge wine
```

Again run the following commands to correct any installation error.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
```

Source:

[Completely remove wine linux Ubuntu systems](http://sourcedigit.com/14942-completely-remove-wine-linux-ubuntu-systems/)

https://askubuntu.com/a/126745/253251

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open Terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
2. Enter the command `sudo apt remove wine --purge`

If the command from step 2 doesn't work use two dashes before 'purge'

Comment: Will purging do any harm?

Comment: no, purge just means it gets rid of all files pertaining to the selected package, in this case `wine`

Comment: none of tge command worked error: unable to locate package wine-purge

Comment: @user109256, copy and paste the command into the terminal.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex package 'wine' is not installed so not removed.