# How do I remove old wine system version?

Tags: package-management, wine, uninstall, playonlinux

I'm trying to install a Windows game through Lutris, and the installer automatically installs a new version of `wine` in order to make it work (`wine 3.3 pba`).

When the installer of the game itself starts running, there is a `wine` version mismatch error. I checked out the system version of `wine` on terminal and it says it's `wine` 2.21 staging.

How do I remove this old version of `wine` so that the installer can do its job?

I installed the old version with `playonlinux` but I removed it through the version manager, but it looks like it wasn't removed. I installed `wine` dependencies with these commands:

```
wget -nc https://repos.wine-staging.com/wine/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely

Answer (score 0):

PlayOnLinux has a gui to control your installed Wine versions.
If you open it, go to Tools > Manage Wine Versions you can then remove and add different ones.

[image: POL Wine Manager]

---

So, to manage wine versions in Lutris, go to Lutris > Manage Runners.

[image: Lutris main window]

Find Wine in the list and select Manage Versions.

[image]

Untick the Wine versions you do not want.

Comment: I did it and I also uninstalled POL but terminal still says that the wine version is 2.21 staging.

Comment: There's a description on how to change wine version in Lutris on their [site](https://lutris.net/faq), i'll try to recreate it and post some screenshots.

Comment: I've added a guide for Lutris, I don't know too much about this program but I imagine it would use a seperate Wine installation than what is on your system by itself. Maybe try what Shayan mentioned and remove Wine completely so we are only left with Lutris' Wine.