# Circular Dependency for Wine after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, wine, dependencies

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and now the Wine program is broken. When I tried to uninstall it (so I could reinstall it from scratch), I get a circular dependency.

```
joseph@joseph-Lenovo-Y50-70:~$ sudo apt-get remove wine1.8
[sudo] password for joseph: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine1.8-amd64 : Depends: wine1.8:any (= 1:1.8.0- 
0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1)
             Recommends: libgif4 but it is not installable
             Recommends: libgnutls26 but it is not installable
             Recommends: wine-gecko2.34 but it is not installable
             Recommends: wine-mono4.5.4 but it is not installable
wine1.8-i386:i386 : Depends: wine1.8:any (= 1:1.8.0- 
0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1)
                 Recommends: libgif4:i386 but it is not 
installable
                 Recommends: libgnutls26:i386 but it is not 
installable
                 Recommends: wine-gecko2.34:i386 but it is not 
installable
                 Recommends: wine-mono4.5.4:i386 but it is not 
installable
wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not 
going to be installed
           Recommends: wine-stable:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1)
wine64 : Depends: libwine (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to 
be installed
      Recommends: wine-stable (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going 
to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no 
packages (or specify a solution).
joseph@joseph-Lenovo-Y50-70:~$ sudo apt-get remove wine1.8-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine1.8 : Depends: wine1.8-amd64 (= 1:1.8.0- 
0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1)
       Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
       Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not 
going to be installed
           Recommends: wine-stable:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1)
wine64 : Depends: libwine (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to 
be installed
      Recommends: wine-stable (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going 
to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no 
packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I then follow the instructions to fix the broken install with `apt --fix-broken install`, I get the following:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
fonts-wine libwine libwine:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
fonts-wine libwine libwine:i386
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 375 MB of additional disk space will be 
used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 667404 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libwine:i386 (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive 
/var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0- 
1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/acledit.dll.so', 
which is also in package wine1.8-i386:i386 1:1.8.0- 
0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken 
pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwine:amd64 (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive 
/var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0- 
1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/wine/acledit.dll.so', which is also in package wine1.8-amd64 
1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken 
pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-wine. 
Preparing to unpack .../fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-wine (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts- 
wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/wine/fonts/coue1255.fon', which is 
also in package wine1.8 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken 
pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've already tried the steps here [How to remove wine completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely) but it didn't help...

Comment: Does no one have any thoughts here?

Comment: No thoughts yet but plenty of questions. Did you have any luck with 18.04?

Comment: thinking about an upgrade to Wine 3.0