# How to remove wine packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, playonlinux

I'm using ubuntu 18.04. I had installed `wine` and `playonlinux` using following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_bionic.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

Now for some reason I had to uninstall `wine` and `playonlinux`. To do so I run following commands:

```
sudo apt remove --purge wine*
sudo apt autoremove wine-*
```

Then I removed the key from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I thought this was enough to remove `wine` and `playonlinux`. But when I run `apt list wine*` I got following output:

```
wine/xenial 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 amd64
wine-binfmt/bionic,bionic 3.0-1ubuntu1 all
wine-development/bionic,bionic 3.6-1 all
wine-stable/bionic,bionic 3.0-1ubuntu1 all
wine1.4/xenial 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 amd64
wine1.4-amd64/xenial 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 amd64
wine1.4-dbg/xenial 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 amd64
wine1.4-dev/xenial 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 amd64
wine1.4-i386/xenial 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 i386
wine1.6/bionic 1:1.8.4ubuntu1 amd64
wine1.6-amd64/bionic 1:1.8.4ubuntu1 amd64
wine1.6-dbg/xenial 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 amd64
wine1.6-dev/bionic 1:1.8.4ubuntu1 amd64
wine1.6-i386/bionic 1:1.8.4ubuntu1 i386
wine32/bionic 3.0-1ubuntu1 i386
wine32-development/bionic 3.6-1 i386
wine32-development-preloader/bionic 3.6-1 i386
wine32-development-tools/bionic 3.6-1 i386
wine32-preloader/bionic 3.0-1ubuntu1 i386
wine32-tools/bionic 3.0-1ubuntu1 i386
wine64/bionic 3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64
wine64-development/bionic 3.6-1 amd64
wine64-development-preloader/bionic 3.6-1 amd64
wine64-development-tools/bionic 3.6-1 amd64
wine64-preloader/bionic 3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64
wine64-tools/bionic 3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64
winefish/bionic,xenial 1.3.3-0dl1ubuntu2 amd64
winetricks/bionic,bionic 0.0+20180217-1 all
```

How could I get rid of those packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove wine completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely)

Comment: @user535733 how to remove them from the list.

Comment: What is the current output of `dpkg -l | grep -i wine`?

Comment: only one line
`ii  libkwineffects11:amd64                          4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               amd64        KDE window manager effects library`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to remove Wine with programmatic way like:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep -i wine | awk '{print $2}')
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

---

Also please note that `apt list` does not list installed packages by default, but has options for doing so - see `man apt` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html):

> `list` (work-in-progress)
>     list is somewhat similar to `dpkg-query --list` in that it can display a list of packages satisfying certain criteria. It supports `glob(7)` patterns for matching package names as well as options to list installed `--installed`), upgradeable (`--upgradeable`) or all available (`--all-versions`) versions.

so you need to specify `--installed` explicitly option with command like:

```
apt list wine* --installed
```

to get correct output.

Comment: thank you, got my answer.

Comment: +1 Kudos! I should have read the existing answers before writing one.

Answer (score 3):

`apt list` isn't doing what you think it does in this context. According to my man page as well as the output of apt list itself, `apt list` is a work in progress with an unstable CLI interface. `apt list --installed` will show you the installed packages. It looks like `apt list` is providing a list of available packages.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following commands verbatim in terminal:

```
cd $HOME
rm -r .wine
rm .config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -r .local/share/applications/wine
rm .local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm .local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

*Be careful that you are typing the write paths or you could delete important files. If you get permissions issues put `sudo` in front of each command*

After deleting the files run command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
```

Do the following to correct any errors:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: doesn't help. wine doesn't appear on the list of `apt list --installed`