# Unistalling wine 4.0.2 from ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wine, uninstall, 19.10

The command:

```
wine --version
```

tells me: wine-4.0.2 (Ubuntu 4.0.2-1). I tried to unistall it with the following commands, but they do not work. How can remote it?

```
sudo apt autoremove wine-devel wine-devel-amd64 wine-devel-i386 winehq-devel winetricks
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove wine-*
sudo apt-get purge winehq-stable
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove wine-stable wine-stable-amd64
```

"Common" output: unable to locate package wine-stable-amd64

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely

Comment: Hello @Puspam thank you very very much for your suggestion! It works:)