# Cannot install wine on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: wine

I tried to install wine like described here https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu but I always get the error

```
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.3~focal)
```

when I try to install wine-stable (via `sudo apt-get install wine-stable`) the following error occurs

```
wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.3~focal)
```

again, going back one step, hence, trying to install `wine-stable-i386` I get

```
wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 (>= 19.06.07) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libudev1:i386 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libglu1:i386
                         Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libsane1:i386
                         Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

I tried different things recommended here like deleting the repository and adding it again and so on but nothing really worked. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Does anyone have a clue how to resolve these errors?

Edit1 - output of `sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Hit:4 https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/2.7.1.2560/linux/Ubuntu_20.04  InRelease
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/smathot/cogscinl/ubuntu focal InRelease                           
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunderme/texstudio/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
```

Comment: why don't you use the install-recommends option as mentioned by the site ? sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Comment: I did! Like I already wrote, I executed the steps EXACTLY like listed on the website.

Comment: If often happens because folks ignored (or failed to understand) a critical instruction: "*If you have previously installed a Wine package from another repository, please remove it and any packages that depend on it (e.g., wine-mono, wine-gecko, winetricks) before attempting to install the WineHQ packages, as they may cause dependency conflicts.*" You are encountering dependency conflicts. There are several other possible reasons.

Comment: @Koen Sorry if I was unclear, I first did the -install-recommends winehq-stable but it failed due to the error shown above I wanted to install the dependency like advised in the FAQ of the WineHQ Wiki.

Comment: Can't reproduce on fresh 20.04 LTS VM.

Comment: @user535733 There shouldn't be any wine installations left. I purged it and removed the corresponding directories https://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely

Comment: @user535733 I added the output